# Error: cannot access java.lang.Object

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using  Visual studio 2015 in which I install xamarin plugin.
I create a cross plateform project and I just want to display a message on the screen of android .However,I get the following error when I try to build:

Error: cannot access java.lang.Object

Comment: sounds like something went wrong with the setup when installing visual studio, also double check that you have java installed and the path variables are defined

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't understand, can u explan more please!
thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re-installing JDK (try latest version) will help you to get rid of this issue. Please try and let me know